# How to include a cursive font from google fonts(with spaces in the font name) into a canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-fonts

Here is my code and I have the font loaded at the head before the script is loaded
here is the code for that

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 1000);
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "#000000";
context.font = "30px Pacifico, cursive";
context.fillText("Hello World", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: well what's `img`?

Comment: You don't need to mention `cursive` in the font, the name is just `Pacifico`. The only actual problem seems that `img` doesn't exist. Otherwise that code works.

Comment: your img is not being declared. draw what img?

Comment: I just posted a fraction of my code, the img is working fine, im sorry for posting half the code but i just thought i might show the relevant details

Comment: btw the actual font name is {'Pacifico', cursive} and when i tried Pacifico it dosent work

Comment: @IsaamThalhathm, no the font is `Pacifico`, cursive is only added as a fallback if `Pacifico` isn't loaded. It's referred to as the font stack when you have multiple fonts separated by a comma.

Comment: 'Pacifico` is the font name. `cursive` is a generic system level font fall back

Answer (score 1):

The question was *How to include a cursive font from google fonts(with spaces in the font name) into a canvas element*

It turns out that the questioner did not need a space in the font being used and the code given worked fine (except for a missing img).

However, in case someone lands here wanting to know how to include a font from google fonts with spaces in the font name here's an example:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT Serif Caption' rel='stylesheet'>
```

i.e. just include the spaces, not need for translation to anything.